# why is my text decoration none not working?

Tags: html, css

The CSS text decoration is not working

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sz9o42cf/2/)

```
a {
   text-decoration: none
}
```

Comment: try with ! important

Comment: tried it, nothing changed.

Comment: It seems to work fine in your fiddle.

Comment: Well it isnt for me. I can see the bullets before the text

Comment: It's always best to put your code directly in your question rather than linking out to it. There is a code snippet option for formatting, which makes it easier than linking out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to remove the bullet you need this:

```
.page-header nav li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

See the update fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/px9g3nLy/